# filechooser in kivy without class

Tags: python, kivy

hi there i new in kivy iam learning without classes i want filechooser but any one tell me kivy filechooserIconView **without class** and not with kivy file only python file

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView
a=GridLayout(cols=1)
def a1():
    global b
    global c
    c.text=str(b.path)
b=FileChooserIconView(path='/storage/emulated/0/')
from functools import partial
c=Button(text='ok')
a.add_widget(c)
b.bind(on_release=a1)
a.add_widget(b)
runTouchApp(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost works, just a couple issues. First, you are binding `on_release` to the `FileChooser`, but I think you want that bound to the Button. Second, our `a1()` method must accept an argument (the button). Here is a modified version of your code with those changes:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView
a=GridLayout(cols=1)
def a1(button):  # handle required arg
    global b
    global c
    c.text=str(b.path)
b=FileChooserIconView(path='/home/jra')
c=Button(text='ok')
a.add_widget(c)
c.bind(on_release=a1)  # bind to button, not FileChooser
a.add_widget(b)
runTouchApp(a)
```